# I don't understand why this code won't run?

Tags: python-3.x

This is my first question here so, sorry if I made any mistakes. 
I am trying to make a simple calculator on python 3 using a class. However, I couldn't figure out why it wouldn't run, it looks fine to me. Here it is:

```
class Math:
    def __init__(self,num1,num2):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2

    def add (self):
        print("Result: " + str(self.num1 + self.num2))
    def subs (self):
        print("Result: " + str(self.num1 - self.num2))

    def mp (self):
        print("Result: " + str(self.num1 * self.num2))
    def div (self):
        print("Result: " + str(self.num1 / self.num2))



operation = print((input("""Operations?: 
 1: Add
 2: Substract
 3: Multiply
 4: Divide
 """)))

num1 = print(input("Enter first number: "))
num2 = print(input("Enter second number: "))
maths = Math(num1,num2)   

if operation == "1":
    maths.add()
elif operation == "2":
    maths.subs()
elif operation == "3":
    maths.mp()
elif operation == "4":
    maths.div()
else:
    print("Undefined key")
```

Comment: What happens when you try to run it - is there an error message, or just no output, or the wrong output, or does it pause forever without doing anything?

Comment: `operation = print(...)` assigns `None` to `operation`. should be `operation = input(...)`.

Comment: @kaya3 it asks the operation, first and the second number but then it executes directly the else statement.

Comment: So your program *does* run, but it does the wrong thing when you run it. Please edit your question to be specific about what it does at the moment, and what you want it to do instead.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I knew I was missing something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `print()` on a string (such as the one given by `input()`) it prints out the string and returns `None`. Each of the values you set below is `None`. You don't want to be printing the values, you want to convert them to integers with the `int()` function instead of printing.

```
operation = print((input("""Operations?: 
 1: Add
 2: Substract
 3: Multiply
 4: Divide
 """)))

num1 = print(input("Enter first number: "))
num2 = print(input("Enter second number: "))
maths = Math(num1,num2)
```

This should become

```
operation = int((input("""Operations?: 
 1: Add
 2: Substract
 3: Multiply
 4: Divide
 """)))

num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))
maths = Math(num1,num2)
```

Comment: Yes, now I got it. It runs now.